Are questions about translation requests on topic?
Sarebbe opportuno supportare domande inerenti richieste di traduzione in Italiano?
Are questions about translation requests on topic?

I'll reply in English, so that future foreign users (which are most likely the ones going to ask for a translation) will find this useful.
I'll borrow a term from StackOverflow, and propose to mark as off-topic any  plzsendtehtranzlation questions (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19780/205473)
I'm not saying that any question about a translation issue is off-topic, but in order to be on topic, they should describe a very specific issue, for instance with the construction of the phrase or the choice of a term in place of another, and show some effort from the OP.
Some examples:

What's the translation of "The pen is on the table" in Italian?

off-topic


I'm trying to translate "The pen is on the table" in Italian, but I a have a few doubts. So far I came up with La penna è sul bancone. Is it correct? I feel like the translation of table could be improved, but I'm not sure how.

on-topic

Io direi di sì, però solo nei casi in cui uno faccia perlomeno un tentativo di traduzione.
